# How to use a Term Meta Field as a link

Tags: taxonomy, post-meta, terms, links

I created a taxonomy called `animal` and a term meta field called `horse`.

I created a function in my functios.php file to make it easier to display the data.

Here is my code:

```
function regular_info_page() {
                $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'animal');
                $result = "";
                if (is_array($terms) || is_object($terms)){
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $term_id = $term->term_id;
                    $result .= get_term_meta( $term_id, 
'horse', true );
                }
            }
                return $result;
            }
```

The meta field `horse` holds a link, and I would like to display the link on my page, but instead of it opening the link, it just reloads the current page.

Here is the code I placed on the page:

`<p><a href="<?php regular_info_page(); ?>">For more info on this Bracha, click here.</a></p>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You’re not echoing the result, it’s just returning which isn’t output to the page. You should be able to change `return $result;` into `echo $result;` and have it display.

Just be aware that as you have your code now, it’s not going to return or echo a proper link.

My guess is you could use something like is found at the link below to do what you need.

https://gist.github.com/petenelson/4020471

Answer (score 0):

@ericb For some reason I can't add a comment, but to me it looks like he put the function code (`return $result`) in his functions.php file, and not on the page, so there is no reason for him to change it to `echo $result`. If anything the `echo` should be in the second piece of code he posted, but it should still display on the page without the `echo`. Just my 2 cents.